Ubuntu 24.04 Fresh install. System 'Settings' freezes when going [System]-[Remote Desktop]
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS fresh install. Installed from USB a few hours ago, and then updated to latest. No extra software installed yet.
After clicking 'Remote Desktop' in the 'System' group in Settings, the Settings app itself freezes. There is a small delay, 1-2 seconds maybe, but it is both quick and 100% reproducible.
Hardware is a HP Elitedesk 800 G2 Mini 35W. i5 6500T 4C CPU, 8GB RAM, and 256GB SSD. The disk was partitioned and formatted as part of the Ubuntu installation - no Windows left. Generic corded Logitech USB mouse, and a Logitech cordless keyboard with a unifying receiver. Screen connected via Displayport to HDMI adapter.
There are no proprietary drivers in use, and I don't seem to have any firmware to update (not sure how it works, but I only have the 'Update Checksums' and 'Verify Firmware' buttons visibile, and neither seems to do anything)
I've tested changing keyboard and mouse, although I only had two Logitech cordless keyboards to choose from, so if it's something with Logitech Unifying receivers in general, I need to get another keyboard.
I'm reasonably tech-savvy, but I haven't used Linux for about 15 years.
Any ideas?
EDIT: To answer @graham: This is, to the best of my knowledge so far, the only thing that freezes. And I am posting this from Firefox running on the computer in question. /EDIT



Nice. 4 views and already a downvote. Can you at least please specify in what way this question isn't good? I have tried searching first. I have stated the problem clearly.

Is that the only thing that freezes? Are you able to use anything else installed by default (such as Firefox) or does every option freeze? [edit] your question accordingly (btw, the -1 is not mine )

I also had this exact problem, so it was good to find your post here. Additionally my settings app crashes constantly on load and I have had to reinstall several times.

same experience, on fresh install in Qemu

Yes, exactly the same. fresh install, but can't enable remote desktop

Ok, apt-get reinstall gnome-remote-desktop seems to have solved it.
An initial shot-in-the-dark apt-get install gnome-remote-desktop indicated that everything was up to date, and no changes were made.
So I took another shot in the dark and did apt-get reinstall gnome-remote-desktop, and rebooted, and now the 'Settings' app no longer freezes.

something maybe to do with the keyring.
after i reinstalled per above - i got a keyring prompt and in the background i saw the 'not responding' dialog, which went away after logging in for keyring.
